# CodeReady Container for OpenShift won't start on Windows 10

Tags: openshift

Two different things might happen:

1 - On the output, get the following messages

```
ERRO unknown error occurred
ERRO unknown error occurred
ERRO unknown error occurred
ERRO unknown error occurred
```

2 - On `~.crc/crc.log`, see the following errors:

```
Error dialing TCP: dial tcp [removed]:22: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or es
tablished connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Disable any VPNs on the computer](https://github.com/code-ready/crc/issues/908#issuecomment-571110088)
- [Create](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/get-started/create-a-virtual-switch-for-hyper-v-virtual-machines) a virtual switch [named crc](https://github.com/code-ready/crc/issues/953#issuecomment-578815768)

It took me some time to figure these out, so sharing